# call to undefined function exif_read_data()

Tags: php, exif

In my application I am getting the following error:

> call to undefined function exif_read_data()

I already have enabled mbstring extension before exif extension but I am still getting this error.

Could anybody give me any hints as to why this error persists?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you restarted your web server? Maybe post the section of your php.ini file where you have these extensions?

Comment: since this is google's no.1 hit on the aforementioned error-message, I think this question should be re-openend after editing

Answer (score 13):

So you php.ini needs to look like this (under Windows):

```
1   extension=php_mbstring.dll
2   extension=php_exif.dll
```

and not:

```
1   extension=php_exif.dll
2   extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

**restart apache** good luck!

**update 1**

Try this code and put back the result

```
 <?php
$ini = get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');
echo '<pre>ini: ', $ini, "\n";

foreach(file($ini) as $l) {
  if ( false!==strpos($l, '_exif') || false!==strpos($l, '_mbstring') ) {
    echo $l;
  }
}
echo '<pre>';
```

**update 2**
check “ext” directory of your PHP installation and see the file `php_exif.dll` was there.
**update 3** try http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Comment: yes, sir/ma'am,
i have done the same thing and also restarted wamp server.
But, still it is not working.

Comment: here is the result:
ini: C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin\php.ini
;extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll

and php_exif.dll and php_mbstring.dll both are there.

Comment: have a Total S/M Restart ?

Comment: now, i have total system restart. but, again, it gives same error.here is code which i am trying, if possible, have a look and guide me.
<?php $exif_data = exif_read_data('image1.jpg');
print_r($exif_data); ?>

Thanks a lot.

Comment: try http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/